# Python, takes 1 positional argument, but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x

Aplicación que no da ningún error excepto uno, el objeto de esta consulta.
Aplicación hecha en VS Code con Qt Designer.
Al final de la aplicación, al final de **main**.py

```
def main():

   inventario = Inventario

   app =QApplication(sys.argv)

   ventana = GestorInventarioAplicacion(inventario)

   ventana.show()

   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':

   main()
```

En

```
ventana = GestorAplicaciónInventario(inventario)
```

recibo el mensaje:

> Se produjo un error excepcion Type Error
> GestorInventarioAplicacion.__init__()
> Takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

Y no me presenta ningún widget en la pantalla.
Dos preguntas:
a) Respecto a la traducción del mensaje de error: ¿significa que `GestorInventarioAplicacion.__init__()` requiere / toma un argumento posicional (únicamente) y yo le he dado dos?
b) ¿Cómo puedo rastrear la ubicación de este error?
Las explicaciones que he encontrado en la red a "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" son muy variadas y difíciles de entender para mí.

Comment: ¿Y qué es GestorInventarioAplicacion?

Comment: @padaleiana , has editado el código del OP dando por sentado que los errores que contenía no forman parte real del código original, privando a los demás de toda la información; esas correcciones debe hacerlas el propio interesado si lo considera necesario...

Comment: @FranciscoJavier no hice ninguna corrección, solo agregué triples acentos graves (```) alrededor del código para darle formato. Podés revisar la edición que hice, en la pestaña "markdown en paralelo". Si te referís a que el código tenía dobles asteriscos, era porque OP mismo aclaraba más abajo "señalando la línea en negritas".

Answer (score 0):

El error es que tienes declarada la clase con un solo parámetro cuando debes dar dos.

Si escribiste lo siguiente:

```
class GestorInventarioAplicacion:
    def __init__(self):
        ... codigo ...
```

solo puedes llamar a la clase sin argumentos:

```
x = GestorInventarioAplicacion()
```

Como le estás pasando un argumento, la declaración correcta debe ser esta:

```
class GestorInventarioAplicacion:
    def __init__(self, inventario):
        ... codigo ...
```

para que funcione tu codigo.

Comment: Sensacional, fabuloso. He modificado def __init

Comment: Decía que, de acuerdo con lo que me habéis dicho, he sustituido def __init__(self): por def __init__(self, inventario): y me funciona `perfectamente. Mil gracias.

Comment: @Baldomero123 si esta respuesta ayudó a resolver el problema, no dudes en [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) (con el "tick" verde).